# <a data-method='something' href ... - POSTs?

Tags: html

yes, it does.

Is this any where documented?

Background: with my RoR Helper I made an error and created Links with `data-method='GET'`. Everthing still worked, only that I got a "Resend Data Warning" when refreshing the page ...

Now I found this strange behavior:  `data-method='GET'`
Works with FF, IE, Chrome

Is this a standard? if yes it makes the Rails `button_to` (with all the form around) obsolette ...

edit: I forgott to say: `_method` is made out of `data-method` and this is as data posted, if i change the 'GET' to a - lets say 'PUT' I get RoR routing errors

an other edit: OK, I try too explain with a better example:

the following line

```
"<a data-method='PUT'  href='?'>post</a>"
```

creates a POST request with _method='PUT' as data

[image: Chrome test with PUT]
[image: FF test with 'GET']

Comment: You need to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: Its not a problem, its more a 'wow',  if you create a <a> with a property 'data-method', the link does not 'GET' it 'POST'. end of the story. try it

Answer (score 2):

no it is not a standard, as long as you say that RAILS Jquery_ujs.js is not a standard.

Rails/Jquery is doing this Magic:

if you take a look here all the magic is gone ...:

```
 $.rails = rails = {
    // Link elements bound by jquery-ujs
    linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote], a[data-disable-with], a[data-disable]',

    // Button elements bound by jquery-ujs
    buttonClickSelector: 'button[data-remote], button[data-confirm]',

    // Select elements bound by jquery-ujs
    inputChangeSelector: 'select[data-remote], input[data-remote], textarea[data-remote]',

    // Form elements bound by jquery-ujs
    formSubmitSelector: 'form',

    // Form input elements bound by jquery-ujs
    formInputClickSelector: 'form input[type=submit], form input[type=image], form button[type=submit], form button:not([type])',

    // Form input elements disabled during form submission
    disableSelector: 'input[data-disable-with]:enabled, button[data-disable-with]:enabled, textarea[data-disable-with]:enabled, input[data-disable]:enabled, button[data-disable]:enabled, textarea[data-disable]:enabled',

    // Form input elements re-enabled after form submission
    enableSelector: 'input[data-disable-with]:disabled, button[data-disable-with]:disabled, textarea[data-disable-with]:disabled, input[data-disable]:disabled, button[data-disable]:disabled, textarea[data-disable]:disabled',

    // Form required input elements
    requiredInputSelector: 'input[name][required]:not([disabled]),textarea[name][required]:not([disabled])',

    // Form file input elements
    fileInputSelector: 'input[type=file]',

    // Link onClick disable selector with possible reenable after remote submission
    linkDisableSelector: 'a[data-disable-with], a[data-disable]',

    // Button onClick disable selector with possible reenable after remote submission
    buttonDisableSelector: 'button[data-remote][data-disable-with], button[data-remote][data-disable]',
```

Comment: since rails >= 5.1.* this all resides in `rails-ujs` now